# 'Why im still getting this error on laravel web, it says about non-statically method.'

Tags: php, laravel

here is the error

> Non-static method App\Models\ISModel::DisplayAllUserList() cannot be called statically

here is my code in controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Models\ISModel;

class ISController extends Controller
{
    public function display_all_user_list(){
           
        echo $result = ISModel::DisplayAllUserList();
    }
}
```

Please answer my problem, Thank you!

Comment: So instantiate the class and call the method on the object

Comment: You're using the [scope resolution operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) to access a [static](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) method that based on the error is not defined as static. Either define `DisplayAllUserList()` as static, or create an instance of your model and call the method using the object operator (`->`).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Laravel, eloquent models do not work like constructors you cannot just call a method on a Model instance, you have to define exactly what you want so since you want to return all models you do it like this

```
ISModel::all()->DisplayAllUserList();
```

I still think this may cause problems since you are calling a method to a collection but you return all the ISModels like this.

Comment: I try it but it appears a new error says SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db.i_s_models' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from 'i_s_models')

Comment: Then Matt I recommend learning the basics of Laravel and how to setup a model/migration/view. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ImtZ5yENzgE&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org